# Trouble with array of integers in java

Tags: java, arrays

This program should allow user to enter values of fall-outs for each month and then output average value of fall-outs and the driest season. It is compiling, but the problem is i can't enter data into array. It lets me to enter the value of the first array element and then tells me there's an error:

```
Enter precipitation for each month: 
Month #01 = 10
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Seasons.In(Seasons.java:16)
at Seasons.main(Seasons.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Seasons {
private ArrayList<Integer> monthList;
private int winter,spring,summer,autumn;
public void In(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter precipitation for each month: ");
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
        System.out.print("Month #"+i+1+" = ");
        int a=in.nextInt();
        monthList.add(i, a);
    }
}
public int Calculate(){
    int Sum = 0;
    for(int element:monthList){
        Sum+=element;
    }
    winter = monthList.get(11) + monthList.get(0) + monthList.get(1);
    spring = monthList.get(2) + monthList.get(3) + monthList.get(4);
    summer = monthList.get(5) + monthList.get(6)+ monthList.get(7);
    autumn = monthList.get(8) + monthList.get(9) + monthList.get(10);
    return Sum;
}
public void Out(int Result){
    System.out.println("Average precipitation for this year is "+ Result/12);
    if(winter<spring && winter<summer && winter<autumn) System.out.println("Winter was the driest season - "+winter);
    else if(spring<summer && spring<autumn) System.out.println("Spring was the driest season - "+spring);
    else if(autumn<summer) System.out.println("Autumn was the driest season - "+autumn);
    else System.out.println("Summer was the driest season - "+summer);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Seasons Precipitation = new Seasons();
    Precipitation.In();
    Precipitation.Out(Precipitation.Calculate());
}
}
```

Will be thankful for any help.

UPD.: Thank you for noticing my unattentive mistake, now it works!

Comment: Which is line 16? Is it `System.out.print("Month #"+i+1+" = ");`?

Comment: Besides the problem you are facing, your naming conventions need to be looked at [link] (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
private ArrayList<Integer> monthList;
```

Currently your list is  null(default value of object) and when you do `monthList.add();` means `null.add()` giving you `Null Pointer`.Change it to

```
private ArrayList<Integer> monthList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialise ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Integer> monthList =new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array list is not initialized

```
private ArrayList<Integer> monthList;
```

should be changed to

```
private ArrayList<Integer> monthList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

HERE YOU GO

You didn't initialize the ArrayList. That's all

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Seasons Precipitation = new Seasons();
    Precipitation.monthList = new ArrayList<Integer>();//INITIALISE
    Precipitation.In();
    Precipitation.Out(Precipitation.Calculate());
}
```

*If it works, kindly mark it as accepted.*

Comment: You're saying what four people have already said before you. How is your answer adding anything to the answers that are already there?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt

Some have mentioned

ArrayList<Integer> monthList =new ArrayList<Integer>;

which is incorrect

It should be

ArrayList<Integer> monthList =new ArrayList<Integer>();